# Error with web application (Eclipse, Spring, GWT) - reportUnusedDeclaredThrownExceptionIncludeDocCommentReference

Tags: eclipse, spring, gwt

I am using spring 3.0.5 and try to run my webapp in eclipse. When I start the application in tomcat we get this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: reportUnusedDeclaredThrownExceptionIncludeDocCommentReference 
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.getCompilerOptions(JdtCompiler.java:338) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.<init>(JdtCompiler.java:174) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:616) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:193) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:390) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:275) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:325) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:104) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:180) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510) 
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

This project is imported through CVS. It start normally on my computer (Win7 64bit), but throws above given error on coleague's computer (Win XP). I don't know if that matters at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Alex: it was a long time ago, but I asked my coleague and he said that the problem was probably in two jar files with the same method in the class in the same package. After removal of redundant jar we made mvn clean and everything was fine.

Answer (score 12):

This looks like some jars are clashing.

Make sure your Eclipse gives priority to GWT hosted mode libraries.

Go to your GWT project properties (In project Explorer right click on the project and select Properties). Then navigate to Java Build Path->Order And Export tab. Move the GWT SDK bundle above any other library (i.e. it should be above the JRE libraries and any other libs you may have - maven libs etc).

This should solve you problem.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry guys......this is a JASPER integration issue. This issue started occurring after I integrated Maven + GWT 2.5.0 with Jasper 4.6.0.

Moving the GWT SDK bundle to the top allows Tomcat to build without any errors, but I was unable to start web application using RunAs --> webapplication from eclipse (STS).

Added the exclusion for jdtcore and this fixed the Tomcat build + Running Webapplication from STS.

```
   <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0</version>
        <exclusions> 
           <exclusion> 
             <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId> 
             <groupId>eclipse</groupId> 
           </exclusion> 
        </exclusions> 
</dependency>
```

Referred to following site for the solution:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/LsOQfBe4ISM

Answer (score 4):

This issue has been fixed by the GWT maven-plugin, see [MGWT-219](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MGWT-219).

So you have to set the *gwtSdkFirstInClasspath* parameter to *true* like this:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.0-1</version>
 <configuration>
  ...
  <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: This was the solution for me, I also did not have jdt or jasper reports in my classpath or in my effective pom. You can use mvn help:effective-pom to look for any other jdt or jasper dependencies. Not sure exactly where the incompatible jar was coming from but the gwtSdkFirstInClassPath resolved it thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is implicit dependency on Jetty JSP which depends on Eclipse Core JDT compiler which has this option... so that you need to exclude it explicitly:

```
 <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
```

Unfortunately, M2E doesn't show this implicit dependency; you can see it only if you run "mvn -X" (debug)

Answer (score 2):

Try these 2 links:

[groups.googlegoogle-web-toolkit](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/b7caa6db68ac5ac8)

and

[osdir.Google-Web-Toolkit](http://osdir.com/ml/Google-Web-Toolkit/2010-03/msg01539.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in development mode. It was because I had just upgraded the selenium-server-standalone-x-yy-z.jar. When I added it to the build path it was added ahead of the GWT jar in the classpath (see the Order and Export tab in Eclipse's build path editor).

I'm not precisely sure which class conflicts, but this fixed it for me.

See also http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/b09dbcde29cd6cb2

Comment: This is exactly what fixed the same problem for me. +1

Answer (score 1):

To solve review classpath of the project and put de GWT-SDK first.

The origin is the GWT compiler that depend of "class" with name collision to another Servlet API class.

Answer (score 1):

I did what Marek told. That fixed my issue

Go to your GWT project properties (In project Explorer right click on the project and select Properties). Then navigate to Java Build Path->Order And Export tab. Move the GWT SDK bundle right to the top.

```
[INFO] Compiling module com.prudential.eSub.eSub
[INFO] [ERROR] Unexpected internal compiler error
[INFO] java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: reportUnusedDeclaredThrownExceptionIncludeDocCommentReference
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.getCompilerOptions(JdtCompiler.java:411)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler$CompilerImpl.<init>(JdtCompiler.java:228)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:717)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:248)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:463)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:388)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:373)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because of the following dependency declared in maven :

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I removed it and `GWT` could be compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution which worked on my colleague's computer was to rename default JRE's `jre\lib\ext` directory (into `ext~`, for example) and thus prevent a lot of unnecessary jars being included in **runtime** classpath.