# Super dev mode GWT with IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, gwt, intellij-idea

I had issues with GWT compiles. I am using GWT 2.7.0 and I use Java 8.

When I start dev-mod I get this exception :

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: originalSourceLevel
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.getStandardCompilerOptions(JdtCompiler.java:611)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.getCompilerOptions(JdtCompiler.java:633)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.JdtCompiler.doCompile(JdtCompiler.java:983)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder$CompileMoreLater.compile(CompilationStateBuilder.java:339)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.doBuildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:580)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:513)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CompilationStateBuilder.buildFrom(CompilationStateBuilder.java:499)
at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.getCompilationState(ModuleDef.java:668)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Recompiler.initWithoutPrecompile(Recompiler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.maybePrecompile(Outbox.java:82)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.Outbox.<init>(Outbox.java:61)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.makeOutboxes(CodeServer.java:156)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.start(CodeServer.java:118)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:91)
at com.google.gwt.dev.codeserver.CodeServer.main(CodeServer.java:50)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.SuperDevListener$1.run(SuperDevListener.java:84)
```

I added `<gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>` in my `pom.xml` and still the same problem. Any suggestion please?

Comment: As far as I know, Java 8 is not supported in GWT 2.7.0. GWT 2.8.0 will be the first GWT version with a limited Java 8 support.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913237/is-java-8-compatable-with-gwt-2-6-or-2-7/29916083#29916083  see also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15693169/java-8-support-in-gwt/15693528#15693528

Comment: And found this: When using Java8 you should add -sourceLevel 1.7 parameter to
DevMode/CodeServer/Compiler.
here http://grokbase.com/t/gg/google-web-toolkit/154wjbj2hd/java-8-is-compatable-with-gwt-2-6-or-2-7

Comment: i added sourceLevel 1.7 parameter to DevMode/CodeServer and changed java8 to java7 and still the same exception

Comment: @el-hoss GWT 2.7 can run completely fine with a Java 8 runtime. What isn't supported is Java 8 language constructs in sources compiled by GWT to JS.

Comment: @Thomas Broyer: That's why I referenced the links to clearify this. The statement "is not supported " is related to some of the new features in Java 8.

Comment: @user3816170: Is it possible that you have an old version of the JdtCompiler on the classpath?

Comment: @ElHoss but "I use Java 8" in the OP is likely not related to "I use some Java 8 features in my sources" but rather to "I use a Java 8 runtime"; and using Java 8 features in the sources would not lead to a `NoSuchFieldError` anyway. So IMO your initial comment was unhelpful and misleading.

Comment: @user3816170 See https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/3915945 which hints at the same JDT classpath issue as El Hoss suggests. I find it strange that `gwtSdkFirstInClasspath` wouldn't solve it though…

Comment: that what configured in my pom.xml : '<version>${gwt.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>true</gwtSdkFirstInClasspath>
                    <copyWebapp>true</copyWebapp>
                    <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>

                    <testTimeOut>180</testTimeOut>
                    <localWorkers>2</localWorkers>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xss2048k -Xmx1024M</extraJvmArgs>
                    <logLevel>INFO</logLevel>

                    <compileReport>true</compileReport>'

Comment: @Thomas Broyer: you are right. After some digging in the web, I realized that it should be classpath issue.

Comment: @El Hoss can you give me more explanation

Comment: I found some hints in the web: the one Thomas mentioned and this two: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689458/gwt-2-6-1-unknown-compile-issue and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429076/error-with-web-application-eclipse-spring-gwt-reportunuseddeclaredthrownex with similar errors

Comment: I moved  the GWT SDK bundle above any other library but still have the same problem !

Answer (score 0):

I find using GWT 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT (nightly) works best with Java 1.8 app. That doesn't mean it won't work with 2.7, like the folks said above. Although I'm not worried about breaking changes either, as I think it's in the last stages of formulation before release.